# How to calculate definite integral in geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there any way to calculate the definite integral in the current version of the geometry node? Or a way to achieve similar results. If not, can this be achieved in python?

The function I want to implement is to generate a FM Signal which is
$\,\,\,A_c\cos\left( 2\pi f_c \,t\,+\int_0^t{m(\tau)d\tau} \right)$ .

At present, I can only set $\,\,m(t)\,\,$ to $\,\,cos(2\pi f_mt)\,\,$, because its integral can be directly replaced by $\,\,sin(2\pi f_mt)\,\,$ instead of integral operation. The figure below is the result.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to perform FM modulation on the waveform in the figure below. The two figures are the geo nodes of wave and the its output shape.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you want to do?

Comment: In general, no.  Unless you can provide a closed form equation as a solution for the indefinite integral, you would need a numerical method to approximate the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to generate a FM signal which need to integrate the signal. This is its expression: https://reurl.cc/ox3ONv

Comment: If the baseband is defined by a curve (or mesh) data, this is probably possible with some dt approximation.

Comment: Yes, I use "Curve Line Node" & "Resample Node" to create a baseband signal. But I have no idea about how to use vertex data to approximate the integral.

Comment: The issue may be the progressive accumulation of the values using GN. Python should do instead.

Comment: after few tests, I'm quite sure a cumulative sum is not possible using geometry nodes. You'll need either Python script or Animation Nodes instead. What's next? please provide an example for 'm' function. And also the final result you're expecting.

Comment: @lemon Hello, I have updated the question, please check it again. Thank you!

Comment: Ben, hello. I'm quite sure one can not create a cumulative sum using geometry nodes. You'll have a least to preprocess the curve to calculate that. So use Python or if you want nodes, install Animation Nodes addon.